# Writing a script to generarte m random outcomes of a Binomial Random Variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, matlab, binomial-distribution, octave

I am brand new to Octave and am trying to become familiar with writing code to simulate random events. How could I write a script that generates $m$ outcomes ffrom the CDF of a binomial random variable $X = Bi(5, 0.2)$, for example?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
function x = generate_bi(n,p,m)
  % generate Bi(n, p) outcomes m times

  x=zeros(1:m);
  for i = 1:m
    successes = 0;
    for j = 1:n
      u = rand;
      if (u <= p)
        successes++;
      endif
    end
    x(i) = successes;
  end
end
```

So to simulate 100 random outcomes, I would call `generate_bi(5, 0.2, 100)`

Comment: Have you looked at `binornd`?  Available in both MATLAB and Octave.

Comment: Another comment: you probably meant `zeros(1,m)` instead of `zeros(1:m)`.

Comment: Two style observations: (1) `n++` and `endif` are not supported by MATLAB.  (2) Using `i` and `j` as loop indices masks functions that return the imaginary unit.  Better avoid them in MATLAB/Octave.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Ok, I seem to have got things working how I expected, but my assignment asks me to generate the random variable in two ways - one by directly using the CDF of the RV, and another by using the fact that the variable is produced using independent Bernoulli experiments. How can I emulate both of this ways in my code? And which way would `binornd` use? I have also just come across binocdf

Comment: I'd say `binornd` uses the CDF and your code follows the other approach.